# How do I trace "fate" of a particular value?

Tags: c, gdb, valgrind, trace

I see some value in some place, but unsure where it has originated in my program. How do I figure out where this value initially comes from?

I expect the following event types to be logged:

- A value originated from constant, arithmetical expression or syscall - the initial event;
- The value was assigned to (or retrieved from) some variable;
- The value was passed as an argument or returned from some function;
- The value was stored to (or retrieved from) some struct;
- By annotating source code with something specific, I triggered the history dump for this value.

For example, for this sample code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct SomeStruct {
    int a;
    int b;
};

struct SomeStruct *globalvar;

int f1(struct SomeStruct* par) {
    return par->a;
}

int f2(struct SomeStruct* par, int q) {
    par->a = q;
    return par->b;
}

void trace_value(int g) {} /* dummy */

int main(void) {
    int f = 31337;

    globalvar = malloc(sizeof(*globalvar));
    f2(globalvar, f);
    struct SomeStruct q = *globalvar;
    int g = f1(&q);

    trace_value(g);

    return 0;
}
```

it should return something like

```
value 31337 originated from constant at fate.c:18
assigned to variable at fate.c:18
retrieved from variable at fate.c:21
passed as argument to function at fate.c:21
received as arument to a function at fate.c:12
assigned to struct field at fate.c:13
copied as a part of struct at fate.c:22
retrieved from struct field at fate.c:9
returned from function at fate.c:10
assigned to variable at fate.c:23
retrieved from variable at fate.c:25
traced at fate.c:25
```

How do I do this or something similar? I expect Valgrind or GDB or some combination should be able to do this.

Comment: Wouldn't an “ordinary” debugger like GDB be more useful for this?

Comment: How do I do this with gdb without O(N) of manual labour, where N is number of such events?

Comment: If you can make sure that the variable is only changed through an accessor function, you can set a breakpoint on it.  If the variable is not set from a lot of places in your program, wrapping access in such a function should not be too much work.

Comment: I don't want to trace **variable**. I want to trace **value**, which is passed from variable to variable. To do this something (i.e. valgrind) should have a bookkeeping attached to all variables, which is also needed for helgrind as far as I understand.

Comment: Oh, okay.  Then I guess I don't know.  But maybe the stack trace at the point where the variable is set to said value could give you a hint?

Comment: Related: https://sourceforge.net/p/valgrind/mailman/message/33225127/

Comment: Analysing strack traces is the manual way. If there were N events, I may need to analyse O(N) times, which is bad.

Comment: It should be possible to build on reverse execution to do this. You (and by you, I mean a script) place a write watchpoint on the most recent location of the value, execute in reverse until it's hit, then place a watchpoint on the source of the move, and repeat.

Comment: Watchpoints + reverse-continue? Looks like closer to the real anser. I have done the demo session and going to format it as answer.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, The idea seems to work. Created my own answer to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combined [idea1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28483401/266720) of using reverse gdb and idea2 from MarkPlotnick's comment of using gdb watchpoints. Here is the demo session, more complete than in original answer:

```
$ gcc -ggdb -Dtrace_value=exit fate.c -o fate
$ gdb -quiet -args ./fate 
Reading symbols from /home/vi/code/_/fate...done.
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8048482: file fate.c, line 18.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/vi/code/_/fate 
warning: Could not load shared library symbols for linux-gate.so.1.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?

Breakpoint 1, main () at fate.c:18
18      int f = 31337;
(gdb) record
(gdb) break 25
(gdb) # traced at fate.c:25
Breakpoint 2 at 0x80484d2: file fate.c, line 25.
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, main () at fate.c:25
25      trace_value(g);
(gdb) # retrieved from variable at fate.c:25
(gdb) watch g
Hardware watchpoint 3: g
(gdb) reverse-continue 
Continuing.
Hardware watchpoint 3: g

Old value = 31337
New value = 134513899
0x080484ce in main () at fate.c:23
23      int g = f1(&q);
(gdb) # assigned to variable at fate.c:23
(gdb) # returned from function at fate.c:10
(gdb) reverse-step
f1 (par=0xffffd670) at fate.c:10
10  }
(gdb) list
5   
6   struct SomeStruct *globalvar;
7   
8   int f1(struct SomeStruct* par) {
9       return par->a;
10  }
11  
12  int f2(struct SomeStruct* par, int q) {
13      par->a = q;
14      return par->b;
(gdb) # retrieved from struct field at fate.c:9
(gdb) print par
$3 = (struct SomeStruct *) 0xffffd670
(gdb) print ((struct SomeStruct *) 0xffffd670)->a
$4 = 31337
(gdb) watch ((struct SomeStruct *) 0xffffd670)->a
Hardware watchpoint 4: ((struct SomeStruct *) 0xffffd670)->a
(gdb) reverse-continue 
Continuing.
Hardware watchpoint 4: ((struct SomeStruct *) 0xffffd670)->a

Old value = 31337
New value = -134716508
0x080484ba in main () at fate.c:22
22      struct SomeStruct q = *globalvar;
(gdb) # copied as a part of struct at fate.c:22
(gdb) print globalvar->a
$5 = 31337
(gdb) watch globalvar->a
Hardware watchpoint 5: globalvar->a
(gdb) reverse-continue 
Continuing.
Hardware watchpoint 5: globalvar->a

Old value = 31337
New value = 0
0x0804846f in f2 (par=0x804a008, q=31337) at fate.c:13
13      par->a = q;
(gdb) # assigned to struct field at fate.c:13
(gdb) # received as arument to a function at fate.c:12
(gdb) list
8   int f1(struct SomeStruct* par) {
9       return par->a;
10  }
11  
12  int f2(struct SomeStruct* par, int q) {
13      par->a = q;
14      return par->b;
15  }
16  
17  int main() {
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0804846f in f2 (par=0x804a008, q=31337) at fate.c:13
#1  0x080484b0 in main () at fate.c:21
(gdb) reverse-finish 
Run back to call of #0  0x0804846f in f2 (par=0x804a008, q=31337) at fate.c:13
0x080484ab in main () at fate.c:21
21      f2(globalvar, f);
(gdb) # passed as argument to function at fate.c:21
(gdb) # retrieved from variable at fate.c:21
(gdb) watch f
Hardware watchpoint 6: f
(gdb) reverse-finish 
"finish" not meaningful in the outermost frame.
(gdb) reverse-continue 
Continuing.
Warning:
Could not insert hardware watchpoint 6.
Could not insert hardware breakpoints:
You may have requested too many hardware breakpoints/watchpoints.

(gdb) delete
Delete all breakpoints? (y or n) y
(gdb) watch f
Hardware watchpoint 7: f
(gdb) reverse-continue 
Continuing.

No more reverse-execution history.
main () at fate.c:18
18      int f = 31337;
(gdb) # assigned to variable at fate.c:18
(gdb) # value 31337 originated from constant at fate.c:18
```

All expected messages in the question statement correspond to some info you have seen in gdb output (as shown in comments).

Comment: If get stopped by `Do you want to auto delete previous execution log entries when record/replay buffer becomes full` then update gdb + use `set record full insn-number-max unlimited; record full`. Be prepared to have gigabytes of virtual memory although.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it could be accomplished *manually* (i.e. running on `gdb` session) in runtime by technique called "reverse debugging". I haven't tried it yet, but GDB version 7.0 documentation [claims](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/news/reversible.html), that it is supported on some platforms.

The method would be something like:

- localize single step where variable is used in the last place (that is, your "starting point")
- analyze source code (so you need debugging symbol and code section available) of stack frame (e.g. by `list`), so you get how this value is obtained (or possibly modified) witihin (e.g. from parameter passed to function)
- step back to previous stack frame and repeat from previous step unless you find its origin

Here is some proof-of-concept session for your sample code. I edited it a bit, as `trace_value` function was undefined. Note that `record` command may  heavily slow down program's execution.

```
$ gdb -q a.out 
Reading symbols from /home/grzegorz/workspace/a.out...done.
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400502: file fate.c, line 22.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/grzegorz/workspace/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, main () at fate.c:22
22      int f = 31337;
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.5.x86_64
(gdb) record
(gdb) b trace_value
Breakpoint 2 at 0x4004f8: file fate.c, line 19.
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, trace_value (g=31337) at fate.c:19
19  void trace_value(int g){}
(gdb) info args
g = 31337
(gdb) reverse-finish
Run back to call of #0  trace_value (g=31337) at fate.c:19
0x0000000000400550 in main () at fate.c:29
29      trace_value(g);
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000400550 in main () at fate.c:29
(gdb) list 29
24      globalvar = malloc(sizeof(*globalvar));
25      f2(globalvar, f);
26      struct SomeStruct q = *globalvar;
27      int g = f1(&q);
28  
29      trace_value(g);
30  
31      return 0;
32  }
```

Few things maybe require some explanation. You need to set breakpoint for `main` at first, as this is when the program execution begins, then enable session recording by `record` command. Then set second breakpoint at `trace_value` function and use `continue` command (`c` in short). This allows you to record whole execution up to moment when `trace_value` is entered. You may think of it as this "starting point", described above.

This of course not the full story. As I described earlier you need to analyze source code of current stack frame an then decide what to do next. You may use `reverse-step` or `reverse-finish` command accordingly to current situation.

Comment: Can you run a demo session on the attached sample code and produce something like the attached expected output?

Comment: Recorded another gdb session, now employing `watch` gdb command.